# How to return just one result from SELECT CASE query?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

i have a table like this

```
DBName  p_server_fqdn   p_server_alias  q_server_fqdn   q_server_alias
cube1   server1.com p1server.com    server5.com q1server.com
cube1   server2.com p1server.com    server6.com q1server.com
cube2   server3.com p2server.com    server7.com q2server.com
cube2   server4.com p2server.com    server8.com q2server.com
```

I want to run a case select query in which i get the alias of a server input that matches a server column with corresponding DBName

this is what im trying so far

```
$SAlias = Invoke-sqlcmd -Query "SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN ($cubeTable.DBName like $CUBE_input) AND ($cubeTable.p_server_fqdn) like $server_input THEN p_server_alias
                        WHEN ($cubeTable.DBName like $CUBE_input) AND ($cubeTable.q_server_fqdn) like $server_input THEN q_server_alias
                        ELSE 'unknown'
                        END as SAlias
                        FROM table $cubeTable" -ConnectionString "connectionstuff" | Select -ExpandProperty SAlias
```

but when i try the query itself in SSMS (with hardcoded values like cube1 and server2.com), i get back 2 rows with the row that dont match the DBName as "unknown" while 1 row shows p_server_alias

result im getting:

[image: result]

i should only get back the 1st row: p1server.com in this case, so why am i also getting unknown?

Comment: You need to post a table structure that matches your query.  `cube_name` doesn't exist.  `query_server` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tibrogargan whoops! Fixed that

Comment: Short answer: You're getting unknown because the query is returning a result for every row in the table.  The output before the distinct is probably `p1server.com` and 3 `Unknown`.  The distinct is just turning all the Unknowns to a single result.  Your query needs to produce only a single row.  Problem is, if no row matches you won't get "Unknown" = you will just get no row.

Comment: @Tibrogargan you're right, I added distinct cause it was producing 4 rows.

Comment: Your challenge is to make a query that produces 1 row.  It's possible to do it so it produces an "Unknown" for no result, but trickier in SQL.  It's going to be easier to get powershell to convert no result into "Unknown" than to do it in a query.  You might want to do that so you can handle DB errors anyway

Comment: @Tibrogargan Tbh I'm surprised this is sounding complicated. I literally thought as soon as the post is submitted I'd get tons of answers cause of how simple the fix to the query should/could be, but the situation now is hilariously reversed lol

Comment: It's not really that complicated, more a matter of using the right tool for the job.  Getting a value for no rows returned is much easier to do in whatever is processing the result rather than in SQL.  It's still possible - just tends to produce overly complex SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @cubeInput = 'cube1';
set @serverInput = 'server6.com';

select
    case when count(*) = 0 then 'UNKNOWN'
      when m.p_server_fqdn = @serverInput then m.p_server_alias 
         when m.q_server_fqdn = @serverInput then m.q_server_alias
    end as alias
from mytable m
where DBName = @cubeInput and (
  p_server_fqdn = @serverInput
  or q_server_fqdn = @serverInput
);
```

here is the implementation of my answer : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b967a22/61

@Cataster solution return 2 rows becouse actualy he get 4 rows (3 rows 'unkown' and 1 row 'p1server.com') then he put distinct in the query. it's make result become 2 rows. 
my solution little bit tricky :).  Using filter in the query. than if we get no row as the result use the count function. So we get 1 row and the value is 0 than show it as 'UNKNOWN'.

Comment: Explain the difference please, "code only" answers really don't provide a lot of value.

Comment: @Tibrogargan thanks for your comment. i have edit my answer with lillte explanation. i hope it can help Cataster to solve his problem.

Comment: @Tibrogargan i am getting an error like this for all columns in the query: Column 'mytable.p_server_fqdn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Rio, i ran this in SSMS, and i am getting an error like this for all columns in the query: Column 'mytable.p_server_fqdn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. maybe sqlfiddle has ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY server mode disabled by default so you didnt get this error?

Comment: ok so by adding GROUP BY all the columns after WHERE clause it resolves it

Comment: @Cataster I'm glad your problem has been solved now